# Moving defined objects in python canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want ot move a defined object in canvas. I know there's a command that moves an object(.move) hovewer it only works on individual items. So how could I move a whole defined object made up of rectangles?
Like the one in the example? Because I need to move hundreds of little objects as one.

```
x=400
y=400



def player(x,y):
    canvas.create_rectangle(x,y,x+50,y+50,fill='black')
    canvas.create_rectangle(x,y+50,x+150,y+150,fill='red')


def moveright(coordinates2):
    global x
    global y
    x=x+200
    y=y+0
    player(x,y)

def moveleft(coordinates3):
    global x
    global y
    x=x-200
    y=y+0
    player(x,y)

def moveup(coordinates4):
    global x
    global y
    x=x+0
    y=y-150
    player(x,y)

def moveright(coordinates5):
    global x
    global y
    x=x+0
    y=y+150
    player(x,y)



canvas.bind_all('<Right>',moveright)
canvas.bind_all('<Left>',moveleft)
canvas.bind_all('<Up>',moveup)
canvas.bind_all('<Down>',movedown)
```

Comment: Please try to reduce this down to a [mcve] We don't need all the code for all the bindings, just the ones related to moving. We also don't need dozens of canvas items when just one or two will do for the purpose of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike what you said in the question, `move` does work for groups of items if you use tags: `canvas.move(<tag or id>, x, y)`.

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()


def move():
    # move all items with the 'group' tag
    canvas.move('group', 10, 10)


canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 30, 30, tags=['group'])
canvas.create_rectangle(20, 40, 50, 70, tags=['group'])
canvas.create_rectangle(60, 50, 80, 60, tags=['group'])

tk.Button(root, text='Move', command=move).pack()
root.mainloop()
```